# How do I get a JSON list of all the visualizations in my CartoDB account?

Tags: carto, api

I'd like to integrate all my CartoDB visualizations on a website, is there a way I can make a call and get them back as JSON?

Comment: Have you seen this https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cartodb/lhKBEhNKgNY/RN9KZPpgkaEJ

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you will use the CartoDB.js library. When you click "Share" on a visualization, you have the option to get an "API" link. See here,

[image: api link]

You will use that with CartoDB.js to have the same visualization on your own website. You can read about CartoDB.js here,

http://developers.cartodb.com/documentation/cartodb-js.html

Comment: That shares that specific visualization, but what I'm looking for is getting a list of all the visualizations.

Comment: So far, we have not included a public function to do this to the API. I don't think there will be one in the foreseeable future. You could create a table in your account and just keep a column of all your visualizations.